# CMake Error while trying to build a uf2 file for the Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

While trying to execute the
`cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..`
command I'm getting the error
`CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly`#
multiple times.

The CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(nrf CXX)

include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)


pico_sdk_init()


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
src/main.cpp
src/NRF24.cpp
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
inc
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
pico_stdlib
hardware_spi
)

pico_add_extra_outputs(${PROJECT_NAME})

pico_enable_stdio_usb(${PROJECT_NAME} 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(${PROJECT_NAME} 0)
```

The CMake error:

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_ASM_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

```
    The pico_sdk_import.cmake code:
    # This is a copy of <PICO_SDK_PATH>/external/pico_sdk_import.cmake
    
    # This can be dropped into an external project to help locate this SDK
    # It should be include()ed prior to project()
    
    if (DEFINED ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH} AND (NOT PICO_SDK_PATH))
        set(PICO_SDK_PATH $ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH})
        message("Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('${PICO_SDK_PATH}')")
    endif ()
    
    if (DEFINED ENV{PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT} AND (NOT PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT))
        set(PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT $ENV{PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT})
        message("Using PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT from environment ('${PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT}')")
    endif ()
    
    if (DEFINED ENV{PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH} AND (NOT PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH))
        set(PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH $ENV{PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH})
        message("Using PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH from environment ('${PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH}')")
    endif ()
    
    set(PICO_SDK_PATH "${PICO_SDK_PATH}" CACHE PATH "Path to the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK")
    set(PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT "${PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT}" CACHE BOOL "Set to ON to fetch copy of SDK from git if not otherwise locatable")
    set(PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH "${PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH}" CACHE FILEPATH "location to download SDK")
    
    if (NOT PICO_SDK_PATH)
        if (PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT)
            include(FetchContent)
            set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR_SAVE ${FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR})
            if (PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH)
                get_filename_component(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR "${PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH}" REALPATH BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
            endif ()
            # GIT_SUBMODULES_RECURSE was added in 3.17
            if (${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.17.0")
                FetchContent_Declare(
                        pico_sdk
                        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk
                        GIT_TAG master
                        GIT_SUBMODULES_RECURSE FALSE
                )
            else ()
                FetchContent_Declare(
                        pico_sdk
                        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk
                        GIT_TAG master
                )
            endif ()
    
            if (NOT pico_sdk)
                message("Downloading Raspberry Pi Pico SDK")
                FetchContent_Populate(pico_sdk)
                set(PICO_SDK_PATH ${pico_sdk_SOURCE_DIR})
            endif ()
            set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR ${FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR_SAVE})
        else ()
            message(FATAL_ERROR
                    "SDK location was not specified. Please set PICO_SDK_PATH or set PICO_SDK_FETCH_FROM_GIT to on to fetch from git."
                    )
        endif ()
    endif ()
    
    get_filename_component(PICO_SDK_PATH "${PICO_SDK_PATH}" REALPATH BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
    if (NOT EXISTS ${PICO_SDK_PATH})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Directory '${PICO_SDK_PATH}' not found")
    endif ()
    
    set(PICO_SDK_INIT_CMAKE_FILE ${PICO_SDK_PATH}/pico_sdk_init.cmake)
    if (NOT EXISTS ${PICO_SDK_INIT_CMAKE_FILE})
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Directory '${PICO_SDK_PATH}' does not appear to contain the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK")
    endif ()
    
    set(PICO_SDK_PATH ${PICO_SDK_PATH} CACHE PATH "Path to the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK" FORCE)
    
    include(${PICO_SDK_INIT_CMAKE_FILE})
```

Comment: What is this `pico_sdk_import.cmake` that you include? Does it include C and assembler source files?

Comment: We don't need its full code, you only need to check if it builds C and assembler source file. Then you need to modify your `project` command appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I Just forgot to add at the CMakeLists.txt file on line 3 C and ASM. New code is:  project(nrf C CXX ASM) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Pico SDK](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk) contains targets that are build with both C and assembler source code.

Because you have limited the project to C++ only with your `project` command, CMake will not check for and configure a C compiler or assembler .

The simplest solution is simply to add those languages to the list in your `project` command:

```
project(nrf CXX C ASM)
```